# Failed host lookup for twilio API fix?

Tags: flutter, dart, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to use the Twilio API with a Whatsapp sender in order to send notifications in my flutter applications. When trying to make the API call the app crashes and throws a couple of exceptions. Not happening because there is nothing in the account sid and auth token(Deleted them so I can show to code).

**Call Stack **:_NativeSocket.lookup. (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:520)
 (Unknown Source:0)
_NativeSocket.staggeredLookup..lookupAddresses. (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:0)
 (Unknown Source:0)

Exceptions: "No address associated with hostname" ,"Failed host lookup: 'api.twilio.com'"

````
Future<void> sendWhatsAppMessage(
    String recipientWhatsAppNumber, String message) async {
  const twilioAccountSid = '';
  const twilioAuthToken = '';
  const twilioNumber = '+15066160178';

  final basicAuth =
      'Basic ${base64Encode(utf8.encode('$twilioAccountSid:$twilioAuthToken'))}';

  final Uri uri = Uri.parse(
      'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/$twilioAccountSid/Messages.json');

  final Map<String, String> body = {
    'To': 'whatsapp:$recipientWhatsAppNumber',
    'From': twilioNumber,
    'Body': message,
  };

  final response = await http.post(
    uri,
    headers: <String, String>{
      'authorization': basicAuth,
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: body,
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print('WhatsApp message sent successfully.');
  } else {
    print(
        'Failed to send WhatsApp message. Status code: ${response.statusCode}');
  }
}```




I tried wrapping the code bits in try and catch blocks and it doesn't even catch the error and crashes the application.
````

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to tell with this much information. It suggests that there is an issue connecting to the Twilio API.

Is internet access enabled in your manifest?

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.app">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Is the application running in an emulator or on a physical device.

If emulator, check the emulator can access the internet? (It may be on airplane mode by default)

Check you can access https://api.twilio.com in a standard browser.